# ngModel - how to manipulate initial model value without making it dirty?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Let's say I want a directive where it takes what the user types in an input and turns it to lowercase.

So I come up with a directive like this (and in this Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/jnE3s8MRr1tFCX0WVYel?p=preview):

```
app.directive('lowerCaseInput', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template:'<input ng-model="vm.input" />',
    scope: {},
    require: ['ngModel', 'lowerCaseInput'],
    controller:function() {},
    link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrls) {
      var ngModel = ctrls[0], vm = ctrls[1];
      ngModel.$render = render;

        // view-> model
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        return toLowerCase(value);
      });

        // model->view
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        return value;
      });

      function render() {
        vm.input = ngModel.$viewValue;
      }

      // view -> model && model-> view
      function toLowerCase(value) {
        return value && value.toLowerCase();
      }

      scope.$watch('vm.input', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if(newVal !== oldVal)
          ngModel.$setViewValue(newVal);
        });
    },
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  }
})
```

However, as you can see in the demo, the model value doesn't get reflected (turned to all lowercase) on the initial pass because the setViewValue is never triggered. Is there a general approach I should be following for situations like this where I do want the directive to change the model based on some rules?

Furthermore, I'd like to avoid turning the control to dirty until the user has actually interacted with it, so even if I did get it to call $setViewValue and caused a $parsers pipeline, I'd want it to realize that the user didn't actually interact with it (thus keeping it $pristine).

Is this possible? If so, what are some best practices concerning it (like is it ok to call $setViewValue from $format -- overwrite ngModel directly? Etc...

Answer (score 5):

The following solution worked for my (using Angular 1.4)

Before updating viewvalue y just save a reference to $setDirty function, and replace it in ngModelCtrl with an empty function. After setting viewvalue I restore back the original function.

```
var tmp = ngModelController.$setDirty;
ngModelController.$setDirty = angular.noop;
ngModelController.$setViewValue(value);
ngModelController.$setDirty = tmp;
```

This worked for me as I'm able to set a default value within my custom directive, and both the input field and form controller remains $pristine.

**Beware:** I'm not using a custom ng-model-options. I didn't try it but I'm sure that if you are using custom debounce timeout, this solution will not work for you, but I think could manage to call the `ngModelController.$setDirty = tmp;` line after the debounce time has expired.

Comment: Hack of the day! This is the only answer that worked as expected. It would be nice to have a flag on $setViewValue that suppressed dirtying.

Comment: This is the geekiest answer!

Comment: It savd my day!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/3x05IUwiHmDizkSvQVi5?p=preview).

```
app.directive('lowerCaseInput', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A', // as attribute to 'decorate' normal input
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
      // view-> model
      ngModel.$parsers.push(toLowerCase);
      // model->view
      ngModel.$formatters.push(toLowerCase);
      
      function toLowerCase(value) {
        return value && value.toLowerCase();
      }
    
      // if input value should reflect modelValue
      el.on('blur', function () {
        if (ngModel.$viewValue !== ngModel.$modelValue) {
          ngModel.$setViewValue(ngModel.$modelValue);
          ngModel.$render();
        }
      });
    }
  }
})
```

First of all: you overly complicated your solution because you created two ngModel instances while you could easly 'decorate' normal text input. In your implementation you assigned all your logic to ngModel on directive element and not to the ngModel of input from your template.

My solution doesn't need to manipulate ngModel on linking phase because this job is left for $formatters. But in case you realy need to manipulate model value without making ngModel `$dirty` you could do something like:

```
var isPristine = ngModel.$pristine;
ngModel.$setViewValue(something);
if (isPristine) { ngModel.$setPristine(); }
```

---

### Edit:

My solution set up `$viewValue` correctly but under the `$modelValue` still stayed incorrect value. *More correct* solution [is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3x05IUwiHmDizkSvQVi5?p=preview) but it's far from "ok" IMO.

Comment: Thanks -- but this keeps the same problem where the original model value stays upper case until you blur it -- and also makes it dirty even though the user doesn't actually change anything (touched maybe should be set -- but not dirty?)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I can't think of anything better [than this](http://plnkr.co/edit/3x05IUwiHmDizkSvQVi5?p=preview) now.

Answer (score 0):

This is what u need for the directive.

```
app.directive('lowerCaseInput', function() {
  function toLowerCase(value) {
    return value && value.toLowerCase();
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input ng-model="getterSetter" ng-model-options="{getterSetter : true}">',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.getterSetter = function(value) {
        return $scope.ngModel = toLowerCase(value || $scope.ngModel);;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Check Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wm1WHK0HWH3hDkLLO1hh?p=preview) and
Documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)